# Karate get response is giving xpath not found error

Tags: karate

I have a soap response sample as below and tried Karate DSL get response.

it worked till parent tag "Fields" after that xpath not found error appeared. Could you please advise.xml response sample:

```
<Entities TotalResults="1">
<Entity Type="test-instance">
<ChildrenCount>
<Value>0</Value> 
</ChildrenCount>
<Fields>
<Field Name="id">
<Value>1234</Value>
</Field>
```

I wanted to grabvalue 1234 from response. I was able to go till Fields using get response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def response =
"""
<root>
<Entity Type="test-instance">
<ChildrenCount>
<Value>0</Value> 
</ChildrenCount>
<Fields>
<Field Name="id">
<Value>1234</Value>
</Field>
</Fields>
</Entity>
</root>
"""
* def id = //Field[@Name='id']/Value
* match id == '1234'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked fine. This will give great momentum on remaining efforts.